# Trigger a macro after a new mail is received

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have a macro that prompts you to save an email to a specified folder before you send it, but I can't get the macro to work for receiving emails.

This is what I have for sending emails:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
      Cancel = Not SaveSentMail(Item)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function SaveSentMail(Item As Outlook.MailItem) As Boolean
    Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    If Item.DeleteAfterSubmit = False Then
        Set F = Application.Session.PickFolder
        If Not F Is Nothing Then
            Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = F
            SaveSentMail = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Is the email coming from a specific person? Or you want to save all the emails that's coming in?

Comment: also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 0):

*Work with **[Application.Startup Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869298.aspx)** and **[Items.ItemAdd Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx)***

> *<sub>**[Items.ItemAdd Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx)** Occurs when one or more items are added to the specified collection. This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once. This event is not available in Microsoft Visual Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript).</sub>*
>
> ---
>
> *<sub>**[Application.Startup Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869298.aspx)** Occurs when Microsoft Outlook is starting, but after all add-in programs have been loaded.</sub>*
>
> ---

*Code Example*

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.mailitem Then
        Set Folder = Application.Session.PickFolder
        If Folder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Item.Move Folder
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `NewMailEx` event of the Application class which is fired when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893.aspx) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance.

Be aware, for users with an Exchange Server account (non-Cached Exchange Mode or Cached Exchange Mode), the event will fire only for messages that arrive at the server after Outlook has started. The event will not fire for messages that are synchronized in Cached Exchange Mode immediately after Outlook starts, nor for messages that are already on the server when Outlook starts in non-Cached Exchange Mode.

Another possible option is to handle the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the `Items` class which is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. Be aware, this event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once (more than 16 - this is a well-known issue in OOM).

A better solution is to check for new items in the folder using the timer's event. Read more about possible solutions in the following articles:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)